# Recursive Tower of Hanoi,Access violation/segmentation fault, on dev c++ compiler

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

//The following code generates access violation or segmentation fault
//i am looking for simple solution to tower of hanoi, which i should write myself
//please indicate flaws in below code rather than giving your elite codes :)

//Recursive solution to Towers of Hanoi problem using three stacks

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  #define max 50

 typedef struct stack{ //union?
        int tos;
        int els[max]; //stack->els[1] = tos
}stack; //template stack?


void toh(int, stack * , stack *, stack *);
void display(stack * );

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the number of discs ( <=50 ) in Tower of Hanoi\n";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    stack *A,*B,*C;
    toh(n, A,B,C);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void toh( int n, stack *A, stack *B, stack *C){
    if ( n == 1 ) {
         int temp = A->els[A->tos]; //switch case i=1,2,3 tos[i]
         A->tos -= 1; //OR stack * A, A->tos?
         C->tos += 1;
         C->els[C->tos] = temp;  
               //     push the popped item in stack C
         cout<<"A\t";
         display(A);
         cout<<"\nB\t";
         display(B);
         cout<<"\nC\t";
         display(C);
    }
    else {
         toh( n-1, A, C, B);
         toh( 1, A, B, C);
         toh( n-1, B, A, C);
    }
}
void display(stack * X){ //and not int[] stack
     cout<<"The stack elements are :\n";
          for( int i = 1; i <= X->tos; i++){//impo to start with 1 if tos = 0 init
               cout<<X->els[i];
               cout<<"\t";
          }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of A, B, C on entry to the `toh` recursion, in your view?

Comment: Steve is hinting to you that your program never creates a single `stack`.

Comment: The run time exception occurs soon after inputting no. of discs i.e. 3 in my case , and program just hangs..A,B,C are towers implemented as stacks, A should contain 3 discs say 3,2,1 bottom to top (if we assume 3>2>1 represent larger disc> medium>smaller) and for B and C they have 3 NULL values each.

Comment: I ama novice and I am sure there is some blunder in my code, but i want to stay as close to this as possible..so that I learn from my own code that what went wrong..i am sure there is a way to implement what I am imagining...just need to know the technicalities probably..

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated. I am looking to define one stack, one push and one pop obviously which can be used in moving discs between any two stacks..the definition of TOH solution is : toh(n,A,B,C) = toh(n-1,A,C,B) toh(1,A,B,C) toh(n-1,B,A,C). so how for this recursive function say toh, should i ensure that moves are from A->B then A->C then B->C .. i want to REUSE maximum amount of code and stick to DRY principle.

Answer (score 4):

As the subtle hints given above were a bit too subtle, look at this code:

```
stack *A,*B,*C;
toh(n, A,B,C);
```

Your pointers are never initialized. Therefore they have unknown values.

The easiest fix is to allocate them on the stack in main, and then pass pointers to the toh function:

```
stack A,B,C;
toh(n, &A,&B,&C);
```

Comment: @user1776433 You did not copy the code in this answer correctly.  `stack A=0,*B=0,*C=0;` creates one `stack` and two pointers.

Comment: @user1776433 Why are you adding errors to the code?  `stack A,B,C;` is  correct code.  It creates 3 stacks.  The code you keep insisting on using `stack *A=0,*B=0,*C=0;` is not correct.  It creates 3 pointers to nowhere.  That's why this posted answer is telling you to stop doing that.

Comment: @user1776433 The flaw in your code has been explained.  The solution to fixing your code has been explained.  It is unclear what "ideas" you are looking for, now that you know what's wrong and what should be done.